# SSIS - fail path not executed in data flow task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I would like import excel files from a folder. Some files are not suitable for importing and need extra work. I would like to filter out these files. This is my data flow:

[image]

I found articles how to continue the flow in case of errors and that goes ok, but my problem is that the tasks on the failure path are not executed when the staging task fails. Can somebody please give me a hint, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason for such behavior is simple - you have two "red" precedence constraint arrows. By default SSDT adds several precedence constrains in "logical AND mode", which means that all conditions have to be satisfied. In your case - both `staging` and `move to facts` tasks should fail. Certainly, this is not the case, and the task `move to importerror folder` is never executed.
To fix it - double click on any of the red precedence constraints, and in the window - select *Logical OR* flag like below.

[image]